# Catch exception thrown by custom function in JEXL

Tags: java, jexl

I added some functions to the JEXL engine wich can be used in the JEXL expressions:

```
Map<String, Object> functions = new HashMap<String, Object>();

mFunctions = new ConstraintFunctions();
functions.put(null, mFunctions);
mEngine.setFunctions(functions);
```

However, some functions can throw exceptions, for example:

```
public String chosen(String questionId) throws NoAnswerException {
        Question<?> question = mQuestionMap.get(questionId);
        SingleSelectAnswer<?> answer = (SingleSelectAnswer<?>) question.getAnswer();
        if (answer == null) {
            throw new NoAnswerException(question);
        }
        return answer.getValue().getId();
}
```

The custom function is called when i interpret an expression. The expression of course holds a call to this function:

```
String expression = "chosen('qID')";
Expression jexl = mEngine.createExpression(expression);
String questionId = (String) mExpression.evaluate(mJexlContext);
```

Unfortunetaly, when this function is called in course of interpretation, if it throws the `NoAnswerException`, the interpreter does not propagete it to me, but throws a general `JEXLException`. Is there any way to catch exceptions from custom functions? I use the [apache commons JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/index.html) engine for this, which is used as a library jar in my project.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how you are calling the method chosen(). Is it via an interface which exists in pre-existing code (e.g. some jar of JEXL)

Comment: So you are basically calling `mExpression.evaluate()` and the caller needs to handle the kind of exception thrown by evaluate and not NoAnswerException. I think you can't achieve this unless you call `chosen()` directly or change the implementation inside JEXL jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, i found an easy solution!

When an exception is thrown in a custom function, JEXL will throw a general `JEXLException`. However, it smartly wraps the original exception in the `JEXLException`, as it's *cause* in particular. So if we want to catch the original, we can write something like this:

```
try {
    String questionId = (String) mExpression.evaluate(mJexlContext);
} catch (JexlException e) {
    Exception original = e.getCause();
    // do something with the original
}
```