# JEXL2.1.1 Script is not throwing exceptions

Tags: java, exception, jexl

I'm trying to execute a function dynamically using JEXL 2.1.1 and a Script.
The function is defined by me and it throws a custom error.

It seems like JEXL catches the exception, but does not propagate it, only shows it.
I really need to know when the exception occurs, because it is a critical error and I want my program to exit.

I tried setting the silent mode to false. 
I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030241/catch-exception-thrown-by-custom-function-in-jexl) that in this mode, JEXL should throw a JEXLException, but it is not in my case. 
I also understand from JEXL website that:

> The JexlException are thrown in "non-silent" mode but since these are
>   RuntimeException, user-code should catch them wherever most
>   appropriate

I checked and no RuntimeException is thrown.
JEXL only logs the error and (in my case) returns false (the method returns a boolean).

How can I force JEXL to throw an error (my error or JEXLException, it doesn't matter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had to set strict mode too.

```
JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
jexl.setSilent(false);
jexl.setStrict(true);
```

I'm not sure if silent mode is actually necessary.